# How to Import 3d graphic to Adobe Dimension

Tags: 3d, dimensions

How to Import 3d graphic to Adobe Dimension. I'm trying to import a 3D graphic from Illustrator to Adobe Domenssion. How to format it and what formats it allows to import.

Answer (score 1):

Only .obj is supported currently. But Adobe is looking to expand that list in the near future.

[Source](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2400079)

Comment: Thank you my friend! What program do you recommend to format (.obj)?

Comment: @SantosMartinez Blender supports the .obj format

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Dimensions is a 3D & 2D compositing / rendering environment, and has no real modeling tools - when using it, one is dependent on pre-existing models or modeling elements in another application as needed.

As far as I know, Illustrator is only an illustration program - not a 3D program. It has the ability to produce some very low-complexity *faux* 3D imagery, based on simplified extrusion or revolves of simple input paths or shapes - these are then parsed (rendered) *within* Illustrator as an ***effect*** - that is, they don't actually exist as 3D models you can access, save or export.

I cannot find any simple way of accessing elements you've created in Illustrator as anything other than 2D graphics.

The .obj file format is a now quite-old but still commonly used 3D file format which is readable and writable by most 3D DCC tools, and can be exported from even as low-end a tool as SketchUp. Blender is free and very effective: other 3D DCCs are not free for the most part, but each have their strengths:
modo, maya, Cinema 4D, 3DS, Houdini.

From the answer above, it seems that Dimensions will import an .obj happily; hopefully the element you made in Illustrator is simple enough to rapidly re-create in Blender or another 3D DCC.